# Namecheap Shared Hosting & Multiple Node JS Apps

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting, namecheap

Is it possible to have multiple Node JS apps run on a single shared hosting plan running cPanel?

I have successfully installed the specific version of Node JS to my cPanel account using the following reference:

http://vinyll.scopyleft.fr/installing-a-custom-version-of-node-on-a-shared-hosting/

Now I just need to take my existing Node JS apps and get them running. I found the following helpful article on this so far:

https://www.ionicrun.com/running-a-node-js-application-on-shared-hosting/

I believe I can make sense of the instructions from the above link. However, the problem becomes how can I run multiple Node JS apps in one cPanel account?

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in different port. Check for free ports and user any of them.
I usually use ports from 3000 to 4000. But, make sure your port is free.

Comment: is it possible to run on port 443 so that express.js can serve web pages like a normal HTTPS web server?

Comment: @Michael Run your app in any available port and user reverse proxy (nginx) to drive all the traffic to that port.

Comment: How does that work if you have a shared IP?  Isn't it possible in that case for other users to be hosting their own content on port 443 as well?